# Browser Extension with java

Tags: java, selenium, browser, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to write Chrome / Chromium extension with java? I tried it with selenium, but it is only capable of automating the browser, not listening to user events.

---

If not, is there any other browser which I can write java extensions for?

Comment: Why would you think you can write browser extensions in Java?

Comment: Java has a very wide field of applications. You can write android and ios apps , mods for some games, your own games, servlets  and create applets. Why not browser extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to write Chrome / Chromium extension with java?

No, you need to convert it to `JS` for this to work, you can use this [tool](http://www.gwtproject.org/?csw=1) for that.

> If not, is there any other browser wich i can write java extensions
>   for?

you can use Firefox checkout [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Java_in_Firefox_Extensions).